# Conflicts with Google PubSub and Google Cloud Vision in same project

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am building a component in Java / Maven that pulls a message off a Google PubSub Subscription, extracts the Google Cloud Storage image location from the message and calls Google Cloud Vision on the image. I have been able to get PubSub functioning in isolation and the Cloud Vision component functioning in isolation. However, when I try to run them together, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.catching(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.spi.DefaultPubSubRpc.translate(DefaultPubSubRpc.java:168)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.spi.DefaultPubSubRpc.pull(DefaultPubSubRpc.java:251)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.PubSubImpl.pullAsync(PubSubImpl.java:491)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.PubSubImpl.pull(PubSubImpl.java:481)
    at xyz.wingman.face_image.GoogleVision.main(GoogleVision.java:68)
    ... 6 more
```

This is the second project this has happened on; the first was a similar conflict between PubSub and Firebase. Based on my research, it appears to be a transitive dependency conflict in Guava versions, but I am stuck on how to structure `pom.xml` to avoid this conflict (if that is indeed the cause):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.skroot.image_face</groupId>
  <artifactId>gcloud-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>gcloud-test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.skroot.image_face.GoogleVision</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.skroot.image_face.GoogleVision</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.skroot</groupId>
      <artifactId>image_face</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
          <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
          <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
          <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
          <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-vision</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev25-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a global exclusion to `pom.xml`, excluding `com.google.guava/guava-jdk5`.